# Are SN1 reactions pseudo unimolecular first order reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics, nucleophilic-substitution

I believe the the Solvent (present in excess) helps in ionisation of R-X to carbocation in Rate Determining step so shouldn't the Rate Determining step be a pseudo-unimolecular reaction as 2 molecules are involved but solvent species has no role in determining the rate?

[image]

Comment: Actually your concept of molecularity is applicable to only simple elementary reactions where the substrate is not so complex. This fact, hence can't be determined theoretically, as far as my knowledge goes( I'm still an undergraduate ) and hence the experimentally determined result, the rate of reaction is directly proportional to concentration of substrate should be accepted, in my opinion.

Comment: Actually your conception of solvent presence influencing the rate of reaction is more of an SN2 reaction concept where the solvent forms a complex with the cationic part of the attacking compound and helps it ionise ( as the solvent is polar aprotic solvent in SN2 reaction kinetics). But this exactly may not be the reason why it is bimolecular.

Comment: The mechanistic approach, in my opinion should be used only for reactions with simple substrates, when you'd like to determine the molecularity of a reaction.

Comment: @user93057 I am not talking about the solvent influence on rate by freeing the nucleophile like in SN2 rather in SN1 solvent doesn't play any role in rate of reaction but its involved in RDS (polarising the R-X bond further as shown in the picture) so I was wondering whether it would be correct to term SN1 as a pseudo-unimolecular reaction as there are many molecules playing a role in RDS but still a first order reaction.

Comment: this link may help: https://www.quora.com/Chemical-Kinetics-Can-SN1-reactions-be-considered-as-pseudo-unimolecular-reactions